# Unexpected cell alignment in xltabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, xltabular

I have the following table:
[image]

Therein, for a reason unknown to me (I am new to this), I get undesired table behavior:

1. The height of the header row is stretched, and some values get centered despite `\settowidth` value being set to the widest header.
2. Cells in ID column are bottom aligned instead of being vertically centered.
3. Changing font size to `%\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}` shifts blue header cell values outside of the visible area (as if aligning them vertically at 90°, hence moving them to the right side)
4. Also: I would like to align ID and ENTRY headers to be vertically and horizontally centered.

I would like not only to be able to fix that, but also to understand better *why* it happens.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperheight=602.78308pt, paperwidth=953.58274pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell,rotating}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cm}{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.69, 0.93, 0.65}\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xm}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1.00, 0.67, 0.67}\ding{55}}%

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\taburulecolor{white}

\definecolor{my-yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.95, 0.8}
\newcommand{\entry}{\cellcolor{my-yellow}}%
\definecolor{my-blue}{rgb}{0.74, 0.84, 0.93}
\newcommand{\dicthead}{\cellcolor{my-blue}}%
\definecolor{my-darkyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.9, 0.6}
\newcommand{\entryhead}{\cellcolor{my-darkyellow}}%

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.9pt}

\begin{document}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont SNazwGeogr}
\begin{xltabular}{30pt}{
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}|
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}|
        *{55}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{0.34cm}|}
    }
           \entryhead{ID} & \entryhead{ENTRY} & \dicthead\rothead{SW} & \dicthead\rothead{WSWOiT} & \dicthead\rothead{Starop} & \dicthead\rothead{SXVI} & \dicthead\rothead{SXVII} & \dicthead\rothead{SGeogr} & \dicthead\rothead{SŁow} & \dicthead\rothead{SNazwGeogr} & \dicthead\rothead{SPedag} & \dicthead\rothead{SWyrTech} & \dicthead\rothead{SŻegl} & \dicthead\rothead{ŚląsM} & \dicthead\rothead{ŚląsMR} & \dicthead\rothead{Dunaj} & \dicthead\rothead{Modrz} & \dicthead\rothead{Ryk} & \dicthead\rothead{SJPDor} & \dicthead\rothead{SL} & \dicthead\rothead{SWil} & \dicthead\rothead{USJP} & \dicthead\rothead{SAut} & \dicthead\rothead{SBot} & \dicthead\rothead{SBrChem} & \dicthead\rothead{SHandl} & \dicthead\rothead{SKol} & \dicthead\rothead{SLeśn} & \dicthead\rothead{SLot} & \dicthead\rothead{SMor} & \dicthead\rothead{SMyśl} & \dicthead\rothead{Sok} & \dicthead\rothead{SOkr} & \dicthead\rothead{SPrzędz} & \dicthead\rothead{SRzem} & \dicthead\rothead{SSłużGeogr} & \dicthead\rothead{SŚlus} & \dicthead\rothead{STakt} & \dicthead\rothead{STech} & \dicthead\rothead{STkac} & \dicthead\rothead{STow} & \dicthead\rothead{SWojsk} & \dicthead\rothead{SZeg} & \dicthead\rothead{SZiel} & \dicthead\rothead{Tey} & \dicthead\rothead{Żer} & \dicthead\rothead{Kok} & \dicthead\rothead{SBłęd} & \dicthead\rothead{SOrt} & \dicthead\rothead{Szob} & \dicthead\rothead{TEM} & \dicthead\rothead{Kop} & \dicthead\rothead{SGJP} & \dicthead\rothead{Karł} & \dicthead\rothead{MSGP} & \dicthead\rothead{Bor} & \dicthead\rothead{Brk} \\\endhead
\hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00001} & \entry{some text}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00002} & \entry{a bit longer text perhaps a little bit too long}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00003} & \entry{some text also quite longish}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00004} & \entry{formy dla przemysłu cementowego i ceramicznego}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00005} & \entry{a bit longer text}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00006} & \entry{word}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00007} & \entry{short text}
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}
\entry{00008} & \entry{a bit longer text again} 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \xrowht[()]{8pt}

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that should resut in the expected output.

I added some comments on the changes I made but if you want to, I can also try to explain what I changed in more detail.

Issue 1 and 3 are caused by your cells being too narrow for the height of the letters. TO overcome this, I slightly reduced the value of `\tabcolsep` from `2pt` to `1.75pt` and at the same time slightly increased the width of the columns from `0.34cm` to `0.3575`. This results in all rotated column headers to be aligned to the bottom of their respective cells.

In order to declutter  the code a bit, I also replaced the repeated use of `dicthead` with a single `\rowcolor` command at the beginning of the line. I also replaced all used of `\entry` with `\columncolor` which I added to the column specifier definition. In order to color the column headers of the first two columns while also vertically and horizontally centering the respective texts, I defined a new command based on `\cellcolor` and `\makecell`'s `thead`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperheight=602.78308pt, paperwidth=953.58274pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell,rotating}
%\usepackage{array} % already loaded by makecell

\usepackage{longtable}% replaces xltabular, since you did not seem to usa any X type columns, longtable is sufficient.


\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cm}{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.69, 0.93, 0.65}\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xm}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1.00, 0.67, 0.67}\ding{55}}%

%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}


%\usepackage{tabu}
%\taburulecolor{white}
% replaced tabu and \taburulecolor with:
\arrayrulecolor{white}

\definecolor{my-yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.95, 0.8}
%\newcommand{\entry}{\cellcolor{my-yellow}}% % replaced with \columncolor
\definecolor{my-blue}{rgb}{0.74, 0.84, 0.93}
%\newcommand{\dicthead}{\cellcolor{my-blue}}% replaced with \rowcolor
\definecolor{my-darkyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.9, 0.6}
\newcommand{\entryhead}{\cellcolor{my-darkyellow}}%

\newcommand{\mythead}[1]{\entryhead\thead{\entryhead #1}} % new command to horizontally and vertically center the column headers of the first two columns, while at the same time adjusting their color

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\myxrowht{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr4pt\relax]{\vphantom{()}}}


\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.9pt}
\begin{document}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.75pt} % slightly smaller value to allow columns to be wider
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont SNazwGeogr}
\begin{longtable}{
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\columncolor{my-yellow}}m{0.8cm}| % \columncolor replaces \entry commands
        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\columncolor{my-yellow}}m{4.2cm}| % \columncolor replaces \entry commands
        *{55}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.3575cm}|} % slightly wider columns to remove alignment issue in column headers.
    }
    \rowcolor{my-blue}       \mythead{ID} & \mythead{ENTRY} & \rothead{SW} & \rothead{WSWOiT} & \rothead{Starop} & \rothead{SXVI} & \rothead{SXVII} & \rothead{SGeogr} & \rothead{SŁow} & \rothead{SNazwGeogr} & \rothead{SPedag} & \rothead{SWyrTech} & \rothead{SŻegl} & \rothead{ŚląsM} & \rothead{ŚląsMR} & \rothead{Dunaj} & \rothead{Modrz} & \rothead{Ryk} & \rothead{SJPDor} & \rothead{SL} & \rothead{SWil} & \rothead{USJP} & \rothead{SAut} & \rothead{SBot} & \rothead{SBrChem} & \rothead{SHandl} & \rothead{SKol} & \rothead{SLeśn} & \rothead{SLot} & \rothead{SMor} & \rothead{SMyśl} & \rothead{Sok} & \rothead{SOkr} & \rothead{SPrzędz} & \rothead{SRzem} & \rothead{SSłużGeogr} & \rothead{SŚlus} & \rothead{STakt} & \rothead{STech} & \rothead{STkac} & \rothead{STow} & \rothead{SWojsk} & \rothead{SZeg} & \rothead{SZiel} & \rothead{Tey} & \rothead{Żer} & \rothead{Kok} & \rothead{SBłęd} & \rothead{SOrt} & \rothead{Szob} & \rothead{TEM} & \rothead{Kop} & \rothead{SGJP} & \rothead{Karł} & \rothead{MSGP} & \rothead{Bor} & \rothead{Brk} \\\endhead
\hline  \myxrowht
\makecell{00001} & some text
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00002}  &  a bit longer text perhaps a little bit too long 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline  \myxrowht
\makecell{00003}  &  some text also quite longish 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00004} &  formy dla przemysłu cementowego i ceramicznego 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00005}  &  a bit longer text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00006} &  word 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00007}  &  short text 
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline \myxrowht
\makecell{00008}  &  a bit longer text again  
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm 
  & \xm & \xm & \xm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm 
  & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm
  & \cm & \cm & \xm & \cm & \xm  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks again. This is almost what I wanted. Is there any inherent incompatibility between `\xrowht` and your modifications? I wanted to keep a constant row height (some will have 2 lines of text, others 1), and `[4pt]` seems to add spacing that results in different heights depending on text content. The biggest mystery to me is which part centered `ID` and `ENTRY`—could you explain that please?

Comment: @MrVocabulary: I started adding a little bit of explanatory text. The resson for the misalignment in the blue colored column headers seems to be that your columns were too narrow for the text in them.

Comment: I initially removed `\rrowht` because I didn't see it created equally tall cells. It also seems to be the culprit for issue 2. It however seems possible to overcome this using `\makecell[cl]{00001}` and the like in the first column. You might need to adjust the second argument of `\xrowht`, though. For a uniform rowheight, you might also explicitly want to add both arguments of *`\xrowht` directly into the definition in order to avoid having to repeat them over and over.

Comment: is there a way to make uniform height, then? I only found two ways: the onet you are using now and `\xrowht`, the latter working for contents of various heights uniformly (I cannot predict in advance which rows will have 2 lines of text)?

Comment: I have just updated my answer and used a modified version of your original `\xrowht` command in combination with `\makecell` for all texts in the first column. I hope this suits your needs.

Comment: Slightly off-topic question: Will all of your entries in the ID column be just continuous numbers? If so, you could add them automatically instead of manually. (No need to renumber all entries if you decide to add a row later on.)

Comment: thank you, this is wonderful! But it seems to have messed up the headers again. And yes, IDs are continuous, but they are generated along with the rest of my dataset outside of LaTeX.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I didn't notice the headers shifted upwards again. I'll see if I can revert that.

Comment: Not really elegant/perfect and depending on the length of the text in the rotated column headers, but probably at least "close enough": `\newcommand{\mythead}[1]{\entryhead\thead[tc]{\entryhead\\\entryhead  #1}}`

Comment: works like charm! You are my favorite person this week ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118732/discussion-between-mrvocabulary-and-leandriis).